# HP Laserjet 1000 printer installation poblem in Ubuntu 13.04 on HP G60-533CL Notebook

Tags: installation, 13.04, printing, hp, plugins

How can I install an HP Laserjet 1000 printer on my HP G60-533CL Notebook on Ubuntu 13.04 ?

Answer (score 3):

First make sure that your printer is already plugged in and powered up.

I installed from the commandline using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-qt4 hplip-gui
```

as PJ Singh suggested, then from the commandline I ran:

```
$ hp-setup
```

and clicked through the GUI to get everything setup. The program auto-detected my printer and a test page printed successfully.

Comment: With Ubuntu 14.04 hp-setup interrupts with the message "Firmware download is Failed".  Here are a workaround but I haven't tried yet: https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/249391 #14

Answer (score 1):

From Software Center,

```
Install "HPLIP Toolbox"
```

Or, from command line

```
sudo apt-get --yes install python-qt4 hplip-gui
```

Then launch "HP Toolbox" and the wizard will guide you through installing your HP printer.

Comment: Thanks, I've done what you said, but after every restart system is prompting to install the plugin for the printer.

Comment: How is your printer connected (network or USB)?  What is the exact message you get?  Is this message in a dialog window, is it within the HP Toolbox app, or is it on the command line or message log?

Comment: Printer is connected through USB and the message displayed is in a window asking to install the plugin for the printer as soon as i switch on the printer. Is it like the plugins are not getting loaded as soon as the system switches on?